# Geology: What's make a group of bedrock a formation?

Tags: geology, bedrock

Geology: What's make a group of bed a formation?

Answer (score 5):

Basically a formation is just a layer or group of layers of rock that is both distinct enough to be identifiable in the field and large enough to show up on a geological map. Usually it is many nearly identical layers grouped together or just one large layer. Its not a hugely precise definition but it is a lot like the term "species" in biology, it's a working definition, created more for usability than precision.

Answer (score 2):

According to Wikipedia, and perfectly consistent with basic historical geological textbooks, a formation is:

[**...the fundamental unit of lithostratigraphy. A formation consists of a certain number of rock strata that have a comparable lithology, facies or other similar properties. ... The concept of formally defined layers or strata is central to the geologic discipline of stratigraphy.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geological_formation)

[image: A geologic cross section of the Grand Canyon. Black numbers correspond to groups of formations and white numbers correspond to formations.]

[**A geologic cross section of the Grand Canyon. Black numbers correspond to groups of formations and white numbers correspond to formations.**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geological_formation)

Typically, formations are traceable across some distance.